# recurring ntfs input/output error

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you repair an “input/output error” in an NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74105/how-do-you-repair-an-input-output-error-in-an-ntfs-partition)

Twice in two weeks, the filesystem table has become corrupted on a ntfs partition. I am able to run ntfsfix and then chkdsk to rebuild the filesystem table. The first time without any loss in data, but the second with significant loss (in one directory).

Both times, I noticed because certain, but different, folders were suddenly unavailable (ie input/output error).

Why is this occurring? What can I do to avoid causing this?

*The setup is windows 7, an extended partition with linux mint 11, and the large ntfs partition in question that is used by both systems regularly.