# inaccessible Windows documents

Tags: mount, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you repair an “input/output error” in an NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74105/how-do-you-repair-an-input-output-error-in-an-ntfs-partition)

A few days ago, I installed xubuntu on my computer and since recently has worked perfectly. But I do not have access to the "documents" folder on the Windows partition anymore. The folder is showed empty.

The folder APPEARS empty, but it is not. In fact if I try to create a subfolder I
 get the message "Unable to create the folder. error input / output."
Can anyone tell me why?