# Problem mounting my internal hard drive...any suggestions?

Tags: mount

I'm a beginner with Ubuntu, booting it via usb in order to see if I can recover files from my hard drive after a crash.  I clicked on my hard drive in order to mount it, and got "Unable to mount 151 GB Filesystem" as the title of an error message.  It then goes on to say:

Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread

failed: Input/output error

Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error

NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware.  In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice.  The usage of the /f parameter is very important!  If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory (e.g. /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1).  Please see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details.*

Does this indicate a total hard drive failure, or is there a way to correct this error and access my files?
Tnx
JW

Answer (score 2):

You can try and install ``ntfsprogs".

```
$ sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
```

Then, try and run "ntfsck" and/or "ntfsfix" on the Windows NTFS partition.

```
$ ntfsck /dev/sda1    #If your partition is /dev/sda1
```

If you're not sure of the Windows partition/device, you can try ``fdisk" command on the Terminal.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
```

Look for the "Device" with "System" as NTFS. Example:

```
Device     Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda5        348483584   373188607    12352512    7  NTFS
```

You can also refer to the following: [How do you repair an "input/output error" in an NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74105/how-do-you-repair-an-input-output-error-in-an-ntfs-partition)