# Getting data off a windows drive by booting with ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows, ntfs

My question is very similar to this one:

[How do you repair an "input/output error" in an NTFS partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74105/how-do-you-repair-an-input-output-error-in-an-ntfs-partition)

But I've given up on repairing the drive, I really just want to be able to get a few files off. It's a windows netbook, and I'm booting off ubuntu on a thumbdrive. If I try to mount the volume, I get the error in the aforementioned post:

```
error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
```

I got the netbook to load windows from a win 7 thumbdrive, and was able to run chkdsk, it completed, and indicated some failed sectors, etc., but even after running that ubuntu still can't mount the volume.

Is there any way to just get a few files off this drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first do a complete copy of the drive with dd to work on a copy and not on the real data, but this requires to have a drive big enough for that.

Since the partition seems to be badly broken, a tool like Testdisk ( http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk ) would likely solve your problem.

Another solution is maybe to simply copy it from windows to a usb key ?

Comment: I ran testdisk, maybe i wasn't understanding things very well, but its looks like it thought the partitions were fine, then I started Photorec, but that looks like its going to take forever, I'm going to give dd a whirl

Comment: dd will just copy the whole partition, you still need later to use photorec/testdisk on it.

Comment: darn, ok, going back to that plan then

Comment: nice, photorec totally worked, great solution