# unable to delete file - rm: cannot remove Input/output error

Tags: command-line, permissions

Some file is in my NTFS file system which I can't delete. It's giving this error:

```
rm: cannot remove `zigBqC04': Input/output error
```

Any other files also could not be copied in that folder and showing error message as:

```
Error opening file 'file-path': Input/output error
```

Any solution.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/74105/44293

Comment: I don't have enough rep to post an answer, but I had this error on WSL. Shut down and restart WSL with `wsl --shutdown; wsl`, then delete the files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like the filesystem has some errors on it. Do full scandisk /checkdisk from windows.
(scan disk for errors)

Comment: That's probably the best one can do without damaging the proprietary filesystem or replacing the filesystem.

Comment: @staticd As of 2019, is this still the best solution? I'm using the latest version of KDE, and am more interested in a *buntu specific solution.

Comment: `'scandisk' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file` did you mean `CHKDSK` perhaps?

Comment: Windows checkdisk has the bad habit of deleting/hiding files and folders that seem erroneous in Windows but not in Linux

Answer (score 54):

I had the same issue, and I wanted to delete the directory. So I tried to use `rm -rf XXX` and also `Shift + Delete` to remove but both failed because of the same error.

I was able to delete the directory by right clicking the directory, choosing `Move to Trash` and then `Empty Trash`.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. Looks like this sort of delete only deletes the information of the directory from the partition table and `rm` tries to delete by overwriting the sectors

Comment: worked for me too. such a odd solution!!! :)

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to know why this workaround is working also...

Comment: not working in my case

Comment: item was moved to trash, but cannot empty the trash...

Comment: You sir are gnius https://i.imgflip.com/v0su9.jpg

Comment: Shift + Delete did the trick, where rm -rf filename failed. Thank you.

Comment: Worked on UDF formated USB stick

Answer (score 3):

A workaround that thankfully worked for me was to plug the drive into a Windows system and delete the offending files and folders using Shift + Delete (immediate delete without Recycle Bin).

After that, the issue seemed to be resolved when the drive was returned to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an NTFS or FAT file system and you don't have access to Windows just copy the files that you want to keep from the USB drive onto your hard drive. Then format the USB drive again using GPARTED or similar partition manager to NTFS or FAT. Followed by copying all the files back onto the USB drive. Worked for me.

Comment: Doesn't work if the external drive is way bigger than any other drive I've got.

Answer (score 2):

I'm on PopOS. It happened to me when I unplugged the external disk before letting the OS flush. I could fix this issue by opening the GUI file manager -> right-click -> delete the parent folder. This time GUI was smarter.

Comment: Pop OS, you say?

Comment: yep, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop!_OS

Comment: this works in ubuntu 20.04 too

Answer (score 0):

may need to be logged in a root to do this. If so, type:

```
sudo su
```

in to Terminal and navigate with terminal to where `zigBqC04` is and `rm <filename>` to remove files or `rmdir <dir>` to delete folders replace <---> with the file or folder name. *Wild cards (* & ?) can be used.*

Comment: I also tried as a root but still can't.