# Something went wrong with my external HD (Ubuntu can't mount it)

Tags: mount, hard-drive, ntfs, external-hdd

Here is my output from the fdisk command:

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00043809

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   973105151   486551552   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       973107198   976771071     1831937    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       973107200   976771071     1831936   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5387f1b4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   625140399   312569176    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

From my limited knowledge of Ubuntu--I'm guessing my external is being detected by my OS, but it's not being mounted. Backstory: I was trying to use an ISO file that I had on my external using AcetoneISO--then everything froze up. I forced a shut down/reboot, then when I rebooted, my HD wouldn't mount. It didn't even give me an error message, it just didn't work. What's up? Help?

EDIT: @Alaa: I was just about to add this info. I have just tried manually mounting my drive, and this is the output:

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/TOSHIBA_EXT
$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/TOSHIBA_EXT
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read $MFTMirr: Input/output error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

EDIT 2: This is the result after attempting to run an NTFSFix

```
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
Mounting volume... ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read $MFTMirr: Input/output error
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
FAILED
Failed to read $MFTMirr: Input/output error
```

Hypothesis: Did I short out the drive when I forced a reboot on it? I know it's bad to do that--but I've had to do that before, both on Windows-based systems and since I started using Ubuntu--and this is the first time anything's gone wrong. Just as an FYI to any answerers, my family is going out to eat fairly shortly, so I will be away for the next hour or so. I'm guessing my next logical step is to run a chkdsk in a windows-based environment, so I will attempt that when I get home. Based on the results of that, what do I do next?

EDIT 3: Still waiting on my chance to get onto the windows system (my Dad's laptop and he's busy using it). I have discovered the command fsck--which apparently is roughly equivalent to chkdsk in a Linux environment. This is the result I get:

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a correct ext2
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
```

I repeated the fsck using e2fsck and the -b 8193 modifier, and got an identical result. Is this information helpful to anyone?

EDIT: I have been unable to use chkdsk on a Windows environment to recover the disk. I did something to it--I'm not sure what. But, the data lost is not life-ending, thankfully. So, I will continue to investigate this issue on my own, and if I come up with a solution I will repost this question, and all relevant information. I thank you all for your help, have a great night! :-)

Comment: What happens if you try to manually mount it? Can you do `sudo mkdir /media/external && sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/external` (all on one line)?

Comment: Alaa, see my edit to my question above--thank you for looking into this with me. :-)

Comment: Well, based on the results of `chkdsk`, you would try and mount the hard drive again =D. It's worth trying this out: http://askubuntu.com/a/74135/52726 (though I think it's probably just the "graphical" method of `chkdsk`), it's still worth a shot after you do `chkdsk`.

Comment: How are you sure your external HDD is detected?(You tried lsusb. Ok, you probably did.) Then I would suggest you remove some cache. okay, this sounds funny, but then it worked here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/475244/why-isnt-my-external-hdd-and-sd-card-found-anywhere-in-ubuntu-12-04-though-lsu/475305#475305 and that issue was similar to this. So worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

fsck is only *roughly* equivalent to chkdisk. As far as I can tell, it's no good for ntfs (hence ntfsfix). For an NTFS disk, it is *always* best to do it from windows. In case the disk has some unrecoverable errors with windows, I will guide you on how to use testdisk to 
a) fix the fs
b) recover the data if all else fails

---

OK, to recover the data, download testdisk and use it:

http://yz.mit.edu/wp/recovering-files-using-testdisk/

(there are screenshots for a similar process -not exactly the one you want, but still helpful: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Undelete_files_from_NTFS_with_TestDisk)

**After** you have done that to try recover use of the drive itself (not the data) you can try a destructive badblock test - this will wipe the drive and map out any bad sectors.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Badblocks

Comment: Looks like chkdsk is no help :-( It wasn't able to recover the disk, and Windows was even unable to perform a format on it. I figured if I could at least get it formatted, then I could get my stuff back with something like Recuva or something. Guess I'm out of luck. The good news is I didn't have my whole life on that drive--I'm not out a whole lot. BUT! I did learn a lot about Ubuntu--as I always do when a problem arises. So, thank you for all your help--I will continue to investigate this independently, and if I come to a solution I will let you all know. Thank you much!

Comment: Just 'I did learn a lot about Ubuntu' might be the best reason to actually do that. The knowledge gained in the process may well com in handy sometime later, when the data is more important. A 320GB drive is fairly small today, when a 3TB drive is some $200+.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem until I recall that this external Hard disk has been encrypted.

The only solution I know is deactivate bitlocker in a Windows 7 or 8,  Pro or enterprise version (home version is not able to read encrypted hard disks).

I hope that all checks you've been doing, have not corrupted data from your hard drive.