# Why isn't my external HDD and SD card found anywhere in Ubuntu 12.04 (though lsusb detects it)?

Tags: 12.04, usb

I used Ubuntu 10.04 before. The external 1TB memory (Toshiba Canvio 3.0 1TB portable USB 3.0 external HDD) was not detected there. So I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 just this morning (as of the date of this post) so as to solve my issue. But the external 1TB memory is still not available. I can't find it anywhere. Also, I have an SD card that will not show up (it showed up in 10.04). Can anyone help me with these problems? I am sure they are somehow related.

Note that `lsusb` detects my device as shown below(This happened in 10.04 and happens in my 12.04 also now):-

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 12d1:1037 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Ideos 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1415:2000 Nam Tai E&E Products Ltd. or OmniVision Technologies, Inc. Sony Playstation Eye 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0480:0200 Toshiba America Info. Systems, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c064 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 058f:6363 Alcor Micro Corp.
```

But neither Nautilus or even Disks Utility for that matter will detect my HDD or SD card. Also note that I once messed up a little bit trying to format this HDD. Now you might say reformat it. But again Disks utility won't detect it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From discussion with you in chat the problem is clear. I guess, you have unknowingly messed up your previous OS, a bit. But even when you upgraded, the issue did not solve(i.e your HDD did not get detected in Nautilus or Disks utility though `lsusb` detected it) as the mess you made was carried on as cache into your new OS(thats my guess). Also you seem to tell that you kind of messed up a formatting process of your HDD before. So even if you clear the cache(and make Disks Utility detect your HDD) your HDD won't be detected(by Nautilus). Now this makes the solution clear and it is presented below:-

### Step 1 - Clear Cache :-

Firstly we must clear cache. For this we can use Ubuntu tweak's "Janitor" feature as explained below:-

- To install Ubuntu tweak run the following commands(one by one) in your terminal(which can be opened with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):-

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`

- Now open Ubuntu tweak from the dash. You can do the same with the terminal too by typing the command:-

`ubuntu-tweak`

- In Ubuntu tweak, select `Start Janitor` and then select all the cache to be cleared(including old kernel, package configurations and the like). Now select `Clean`. This might take a while.
- After this reboot your PC.

### Step 2 - Formatting your HDD :-

You must now be able to see your external Hard Disk Drive in the Disks utility(which can be found in the dash as Disks) but not Nautilus. For your HDD to work normally, in Nautilus, you must reformat it and then mount it. I will explain how to do this below:

- Select your HDD.
- In disks utility you will see three icons as shown below :-

[image]

- Now press the first button. This will unmount the HDD. (Note that you may not want to do this because already it may be unmounted in your case)
- Then press the gear like icon(the third one) and select Format as shown below :-

[image]

- This should format your HDD. Now mount it again by pressing the first icon.

This should detect your HDD normally and you must able to work with it normally too!

As with the SD card you must connect and check it now and it should work.(And from your chat discussion it actually did get detected!)

PS :- Here is the link to the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14846/discussion-between-nick-anthony-and-venki) in which the issue was discussed.