# External Hard Drive Won't Mount on Ubuntu; Previous Solutions Did Not Work

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, external-hdd

My 4 TB Seagate BUP Fast HDD won't mount on my laptop, but it works fine on my Grandma's Ubuntu computer and my friend's PC. It is recognized in Disks, but won't mount, even when I tried the solutions listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318987/ubuntu-doesnt-see-external-usb-hard-disk). Disks is telling me that Partition 2 (/dev/sdc2) is "Mounted at /mnt", but I don't see it anywhere. I'm not sure what to do.

**EDIT1:**
Add output of blkid

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null 

/dev/sda1: UUID="d4dd2f23-0638-4364-a0aa-a24d0098ce46" TYPE="ext2" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="NP8qMG-N13f-NSTd-t2dY-0HB2-seND-iIwyKu" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="1724975b-e000-44f5-a077-1b9ef5fce1e0" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="2882828f-b45b-4899-941f-d68a54cdfbfa" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="3537-6261" TYPE="vfat"
```

**EDIT2:**
Added output of
`sudo parted -l`

```
Model: ATA WDC WD5000BPVT-2 (scsi) 
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B 
Partition Table: msdos 

Number Start   End    Size   Type     File system   Flags 
  1    1049kB  256MB  255MB  primary  ext2          boot 
  2    257MB   500GB  500GB  extended 
  5    257MB   500GB  500GB  logical                lvm 

Model: Generic- Multi-Card (scsi) 
Disk /dev/sdb: 2033MB 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B 
Partition Table: msdos

Number Start   End     Size    Type     File system   Flags 
  1    127kB   2031 MB 2031 MB primary  fat16 

  Error: /dev/sdd: unrecognized disk label 
  Warning: Error fsyncing/closing 
  /dev/sdd: Input/output error Retry/Ignore?
```

Comment: You need to provide more information, especially the method you used to mount it at /mnt, and perhaps the output of `sudo blkid -c /dev/null`.

Comment: I've since unmounted it and I can't remember for sure which method I used to mount it. The output of `sudo blkid -c /dev/null` is 
`/dev/sda1: UUID="d4dd2f23-0638-4364-a0aa-a24d0098ce46" TYPE="ext2"
/dev/sda5: UUID="NP8qMG-N13f-NSTd-t2dY-0HB2-seND-iIwyKu" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="1724975b-e000-44f5-a077-1b9ef5fce1e0" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="2882828f-b45b-4899-941f-d68a54cdfbfa" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdb1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="3537-6261" TYPE="vfat"`

Comment: I edited your original comment to add the output of the `blkid` command.  Not only is this the correct place to put it, but it's much easier for anyone to read with formatting.

Comment: I don't see any disk labled `sdc` at all - is the Seagate drive connected?  What is sdb?  If you're not sure, perhaps you should also run `sudo parted -l` to list drive names with capacities.  But make sure the Seagate is connected.

Comment: The Seagate is connected for sure - it's still listed in Disks. When I run `sudo parted -l` I get
`Model: ATA WDC WD5000BPVT-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start    End    Size  Type     File system  Flags
1       1049kB   256MB  255MB primary  ext2         boot
2       257MB    500GB  500GB extended
5       257MB    500GB  500GB logical               lvm

Model: Generic- Multi-Card (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2033MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos`

Comment: `Number  Start  End     Size    Type    File system   Flags
1        127kB  2031 MB 2031 MB primary fat16


Error: /dev/sdd: unrecognized disk label
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdd: Input/output error
Retry/Ignore?`

Comment: I edited you post again to make the output readable; this is the last time I'll do that, so if you expect anyone to help, you should try to help by making it readable.  I'm not sure what's going on with the drive, but you need to fix that problem before you even think about mounting it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but withe an external drive. Then I recalled that this external Hard disk has been encrypted.

The only solution I know is deactivate bitlocker in a Windows 7 or 8, Pro or enterprise version (home version is not able to read encrypted hard disks).

I hope that all checks you've been doing, have not corrupted data from your hard drive.

The question may be related with [this other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332263/something-went-wrong-with-my-external-hd-ubuntu-cant-mount-it).