# How to mount problematic internal hard disk using ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10

I have a laptop with windows 7. One day i cannot access windows. So I'M trying to use Ubuntu 13.10 live USB ("try only" version) to retrieve important files in the internal hard disk.

when I try to open the internal hard disk it says that:

```
Unable to access "86Gb Volume"

Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ubuntu/34BC6628BC65E538: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/ubuntu/34BC6628BC65E538"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Help me, please

Comment: I'd use a virtual machine with windows to mount it...

Comment: I'd use the windows installation dvd ...

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/74105/how-do-you-repair-an-input-output-error-in-an-ntfs-partition

Answer (score 0):

I/O errors (input-output) can be simply a small fault in the NTFS filesystem, or the disk itself could be damaged.

The FIRST thing to try, is either use `CHKDSK /f` using Windows, or try through Ubuntu with `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXy` (similar to CHKDSK but less powerful) - *where "sdXy" is the partition name, for example "sdb2". you can know the name of your partition with `sudo parted -l`*

---

Otherwise, if the disk might be physically damaged, you could try to manually mount the hard drive. If that doesn't work, I can indicate another way (copy the entire drive with `dd`, mount in loop the image, and extract readable content), which requiers a lot of : time/free space.

#### Manually mount your hard drive

**Step 1** : create the directory

```
 sudo mkdir /mnt/RESCUE
```

**Step 2** : mount the drive

```
sudo mount -o loop /dev/sdb2 /mnt/RESCUE
```

**Step 3** : copy the content elsewhere

**Step 4** : once you have everything you want, you use `gparted` to erase the disk and his partition table. I recommend creating a temporary EXT4 or FAT filesystem, and delete that before reusing the disk.