# Can't access my Windows 7 Hard Disk from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, windows, mount, windows-7, hard-drive

Alright, so I really need help now.

I am not gonna tell the story about how my Windows broke, but what I need is to transfer some of my files which I had on Windows through Linux to a USB Flash Drive. But I end up with this error while trying to go into my 1 TB Volume:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ubuntu/1E48BCAD48BC85551: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/ubuntu/1E48BCAD48BC85551"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

My Windows is not working properly, and I NEED to transfer those files. PLEASE help me! Is there any code I can use? Don't ask me about the repair disk of Windows, it didn't work since it got extremely slow and I left it "loading" on a windows background with my mouse for the night.

All I need is to transfer files from my 1 TB Volume onto my flash drive. I know what to do next, this is just all I need.

Comment: Comeon, search before asking? http://askubuntu.com/questions/74105/how-do-you-repair-an-input-output-error-in-an-ntfs-partition - it was second google when I searched the error: `Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error`

Comment: ntfsfix did not work and I am only running this linux on a flash drive, so I can't install virtualbox, and as I told, I tried with the repair and recovery disks, it didn't work.

Comment: Well then the other answers are saying that you can't do it without the recovery CD. Try asking this on [su], and include how you broke the windows installation there.

Comment: Did as you said.. hope I get answers there.