# how do i fix a mounting error with an external drive

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

the other day I stupidly inserted my bootable usb stick in my laptop alongside my 1.5 TB external drive. My external drive worked excellent before but now I get this:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/soninjr/Black: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/soninjr/Black"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to sync device /dev/sdb1: Remote I/O error
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

needless to say I'm not that far advanced in Linux to know what to do about this. Please help if you can it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: " I'm not that far advanced in Linux " but it is a Windows problem. And the probable solution is in the message: "run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice". See http://askubuntu.com/questions/74105/how-do-you-repair-an-input-output-error-in-an-ntfs-partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that $MFT does not match $MFTMirr. MFT (Master File Table) is a part of the NTFS file system your drive is formatted with. It is like an address book for the system to remember where which files are stored. Because this table is so important, there is a mirrored copy of it.

In your case, the original table and its mirror do not contain the same data, so there is anything wrong with the hdd's file system. Try and hope that Windows' `chkdsk /f` or another NTFS repairing tool can fix this. Greetings and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys I was hoping there would be a fix for this in Ubuntu. Unfortunately my laptop with Windows has a broken screen. Thanks for confirming my worst fear :(

Comment: If you can't access a Windows machine, repairing the drive is still possible, but a bit more work to do.  
Install ntfsprogs by running `sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs`. Then you can run `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1` which should work on your MFT and repair it. (I did not know about this until I just researched it either, that's why I only could suggest you to let Windows do it...)

Comment: To be awesome is nice, but it would be even more awesome, if you could help me to reach my personal goal of today to reach 500 rep (having 490 by now) points by upvoting my answer... Thanks! :)