# Unable to mount usb error

Tags: 14.04, mount, automount, mountpoint, unmount

I am trying to mount usb on 14.04 LTS(Usually wors fine),getting error

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/username/383255103254D48A: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/shan/383255103254D48A"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g. /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details.
```

Then i run the command `sudo blkid` then results

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="54FEB6FCFEB6D608" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="081CC4AF1CC498D8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda4: LABEL="New Volume" UUID="1E30CEAB30CE896B" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="917680eb-96c8-4a8e-bf77-fde42322ea6a" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="513e2c74-d8e0-4d89-a547-cf984f1edc3d" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="383255103254D48A" TYPE="ntfs"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74105/how-do-you-repair-an-input-output-error-in-an-ntfs-partition#156882

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, either your USB drive has died, or the filesystem needs to be repaired.

You can try to repair it from Linux with:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

And if that doesn't work, you'll have to run `chkdsk` on it from a Windows box.

Comment: @user214306 - Since it works, please consider accepting and/or upvoting my answer :)

Comment: Yes, I am trying .. there are some time limits...

Comment: If you want to format the drive, losing your data, you can do so with gparted: `sudo apt-get install gparted`